# The question structure of StackExchange sites is driving me insane!

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to know how a question like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917019/are-automatic-log-outs-standard-with-some-windows-server-updates considered off topic.  I want to know from a coder's perspective how updates may affect VB.Net web coding.  Do I have to spell that out every time I post a question that may involve more than just straight code?  It seems like any of the higher level users and moderators just kind of kill questions that they shouldn't very quickly.

I have read the guidelines and suggestions on the StackExchange sites thoroughly and I still can't figure out a solid pattern to avoid things getting closed.  Is rewording something like that question really that important?  And, why would Super User really be a better place for that question?  Would generic computer enthusiasts really be better to answer something to do with VB.Net Forms Authentication?  Or, am I just missing something entirely?

Comment: Unless one of us happens to be a Microsoft employee intimately familiar with the inner workings of Windows Server, how would we actually know this?  There could be hundreds of potential states and combinations of states that cause a log out or reboot; the prima-facie answer to your Stack Overflow question is "probably, if the conditions are right."

Comment: To answer your question here directly, yes, we need to know the coder's perspective.  That automatic logouts occur when updating Windows Server is normally only of interest to a system administrator, not a software developer.  We can't be reasonably asked to provide an answer to every question that *might possibly* be of passing interest to a software developer.

Comment: Why is it so hard to ask a question that just requires a, "Yes, I have seen that happen with my web app before."  or a, "No, you most likely need to look at your code because the cookie shouldn't be reset from a Windows Update."  It seems like you need both pieces, to mention the code and to mention the server.

Comment: I can understand that in a bigger company, those are 2 different people but in most smaller places, one person could be managing both.

Comment: There's a lot of software/hardware/os question noise that is muted in day-to-day close operations. Many of that muted noise is new users finding the site to ask a question that belongs on superuser because they provide no context for development purposes (and usually have no context.) Approach the problem from a mod perspective: you're used to seeing that type of question... you don't have any evidence that this isn't a standard consumer question... what do you do?

Comment: In general, "Has anyone seen this?" questions don't fare well on any of the Stack Exchange sites.  It's the moral equivalent of throwing spaghetti against the wall, and seeing if any will stick.  I did notice that you didn't show us any of your efforts at researching the problem.

Comment: @Joe Because the rules are strict, friend. But they're strict for a reason. This site fields a lot of questions in a day, so a lot of people who can close are quick to read it, decide at face value, and act accordingly, not consider if it may be meant in relation to code or not. Just take a breather, reword your question, and if it still doesn't fit the scope of the site, try to understand _why_ it doesn't fit. The Q&A style is a bit difficult to adjust to, but with a little effort you can get it.

Comment: @Joe The fact that your software developer is also doing sysadmin work doesn't mean he should be asking his sysadmin question on a programming site, it means that he should be going to the appropriate site depending on what the topic he is asking about applies to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the biggest problem is that most of the things I have searched on the topic don't yield any results that would point me to anything linkable other than failed Google searches.  If I could find anything relevant, I would link it.  I can understand that people want to see some effort put forth by the question asker but sometimes it seems that search engines aren't finding anything to point me in a suitable direction.

Comment: @joe: Quite right.  But the last thing we want to do is provide other people on the Internet with yet another failed Google Search.  We want to provide an *answer.*  To do that, we need to field questions that are *answerable.*

Comment: @Servy I still don't get how knowing how other things affect your software is automatically someone else's job.

Comment: @Joe So every sysadmin question is automatically a programming question just because it can possibly affect software in some way?  Sorry, but no, not all sysadmin questions are programming questions, even if they can possibly affect software in some way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey how am I supposed to determine whether or not the two things are linked without asking?  That seemed like something that could easily be a yes or no question to someone that has experience with the same authentication type.  And, it seems like random information is everywhere for forms authentication but nothing relating server updates to users being booted.

Comment: @Servy How am I going to expect a sysadmin to know anything about VB.Net Form Authentication?  This argument seems like a catch 22.

Comment: How is a "yes" or "no" answer to that question actually going to help you or anyone else with a specific programming problem?

Comment: @Joe Facts, observations, attempts (failed or otherwise), and output is always paramount on SO. If you could send exactly one message to the moon no greater than 1000 words describing a problem on earth, and all of earth's existence depended on it, wouldn't you want to provide every piece of relevant information about what the issue was, and make it as succinct as possible?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It would merely establish that there is a connection between the two and that code troubleshooting may not be necessary for that particular scenario.

Comment: Since you didn't provide a coding scenario, there's really no way to know for sure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If it is a question related to if it is the .Net Framework, my code should be irrelevant unless I already know that my code is to blame and not the framework.

Comment: Odds are about 1000:1 that the problem is in your code and not the vendor libraries.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Have you seen this problem recently or are you going off of previous experience of other sorts?

Comment: That was just a general comment, not specific to this issue.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I kind of read your first comment backwards thinking that you were blaming the vendor.  It would make perfect sense that it would be our code but with no errors reported, there is no direction to even start troubleshooting besides making a VM that we can abuse to run the app on and try to uninstall and re-install updates while adding tons of bug logging code everywhere if we don't know which part of our code is the problem and no errors are being logged already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading your question, it looks like you actually had a good question, but I will admit that you framed it in such a way that some lazy readers might get the impression that it's not code-related and vote to close(and they have the right to be lazy when they're giving away advice for free)

At first glance, it looks like you're asking for Microsoft Policies.

What I'd recommend is re-framing your question so that It's more about your problem and how to solve it, if you even can solve it.

> **Users Automatically logged out of application after Windows Updates**
>
> Users that were logged into a (website?) I had developed were automatically logged off. After windows updates occurred on the server.
>
> The server uses  **VB.Net with Forms Authentication**
>
> No errors were logged during any part of the updates or after.
>
> Other relevant information/ information about the system, the webserver, logs, possible reproduction steps etc.
>
> Why did this happen? and What can I do to prevent it in the future?

That way, you give potential answers an easy to understand problem.  They have the context, and they have a clear mission statement.

Comment: Thanks for taking to time to look at this matter closely.  It is often hard for me to restructure my thought process in such a way that it can fit the criteria of the StackExchange.  Just by simply wording what I wrote in a different order, it does seem to fit better.

Comment: Also, I have no clue how to replicate it.  We could try to uninstall and re-install the updates after putting a ton of bug logging code in the app but I have no clue how bad that might mess up things more or cause other problems.  Since this was very recent (hence the inclusion of the KB update numbers) I figured that if someone had the same exact issue because of those updates now would be the time to ask, not next week when people have forgotten about the problem.  If we take the time to add tons more bug logging code and re-install updates, we could be killing our chances at an answer.

Comment: After looking at your wording again, I'm getting that I shouldn't even mention server info in order to not be made off topic?  That seems really odd because other people on this question were suggesting I should add all available information but that is the reason my question was made off topic.  My head just feels like it is going to explode trying to do something so simple, asking a question.

Comment: @Joe I kinda glossed over server information, because what I know about your server, and the service that runs your website is very limited.  You should still include that information if you think it would be helpful to people answering your question

Comment: @Joe If you can't feasibly reproduce that's fine, but you should at least look into it a little bit.  For instance: if you restart the machine, does that log people out?

Comment: I just want to avoid the question being disregarded if there is too much server information.  It seems like every question walks a thin line of being rejected here.

Comment: @Joe And as far as messing stuff up when you try to reproduce problems, you might look into getting a separate testing server that you can do that kind of stuff to

Comment: @Joe The important part is to get visitors to read about your coding problem **first**, so that they're in the right mindset

Comment: Ahh yeah, I should include that...  The answer is no.  Restarting the machine does nothing and recycling the application pool also doesn't log anyone out either.  Only the updates have caused this issue.

Comment: So, you're saying that I need to order it right and make sure that more information involves enough code so that other users feel it is on topic and that the server info is just a bonus to help solve the problem?

Comment: I have edited the original question with some of your suggestions and whoever voted it down removed that.  Maybe the restructure is just what it needed.  Take a look if you want.  I tried to use all of your suggestions to the best I can after looking at this too long today.  [Here is the result.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917019/users-automatically-logged-out-of-application-after-windows-updates)